# Return true if index+1 of my array is one of those numbers

Tags: javascript, math

In react I map array with images, and every few images one has diffrent class. But I don't know how to code this. So images with diffrent class is nr 4,5,18,19,32,33... so as you can see, it starts from 4 and then adds 14 and so on, and same with 5, adds 14 and another 14 etc. How can I code this, so if index+1 of my images is one of those numbers it returns true?

Comment: pseudo code `(index + 1 - 4) % 14 in [0,1]` !?

Comment: _“and every few images one has diffrent class”_ - why, what for, what is the end purpose? _Might_ be a problem that could be solved with CSS `:nth-child()` selector alone already.

Comment: Thanks luk2302, that's what I was looking for. What's the purpose? It's just a fancy layout gallery with images

Comment: @luk2302.  Wouldn't `(index + 1) % 14 in [4, 5]` be equivalent and more explicit?

Answer (score 1):

You could

- add an offset `-4`
- divide by two, get the integer value and
- check if the remainder with seven is zero.

```js
const check = v => (v - 4 >> 1) % 7 === 0;

console.log(...[4, 5, 18, 19, 32, 33].map(check));
console.log(...[0, 1, 2, 3, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10, 11, 12, 13, 14, 15, 16, 17, 20, 21].map(check));
```

Comment: The code in comment above seems easier, but this works too, thank you:)